# Audio Recording not working in Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: android, audiorecord, audioformat

I am developing an android application, in that i want to record audio and save into a folder.

I have tried this sample code, its reading data from audio object(AudioRecord) but the same application reading only **0 bytes** in **SAMSUNG GALAXY S5(USB 3.0)** Device

Here my code..

```
    private int min_buff;
    private int len=0;
    private AudioRecord record;
    private DataOutputStream dos;
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/demo.mp4");
     Handler handler = new Handler();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final Button buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            final Button buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                buttonStop.setEnabled(true);
                startDownload();
            }
        });
       buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            stopDownload();
        }
    });

    }

     public void startDownload(){

            OutputStream os = null;
            try {
                os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

            try {
                //       Create a DataOuputStream to write the audio data into the saved file.
                  min_buff = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, 
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                      record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,    min_buff);

                      byte[] buffer = new byte[min_buff]; 
                      record.startRecording();

                      while (len < min_buff) {
                             int bufferReadResult = record.read(buffer, 0, min_buff);
                             for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++){
                                 Log.e("Reading", "Buffer Value :"+buffer[i]);
                                 dos.writeShort(buffer[i]);
                             }
                             len += min_buff; 
                      } 
                     record.stop();
                     dos.close();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("AptioudioRecord","Recording Failed " +e);
            }



        }

        public void stopDownload(){
           System.exit(0);      
        }
```

and i have also added permission in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

While reading  `record.read(buffer, 0, min_buff);`  `buffer` filling with 0 only

Please help on this.

Thanks

Comment: I also faced same problem. Please let me know if you find solution. Thanks.